# 'scrapy: command not found' even though requirements are already satisfied

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, macos-catalina

Im trying to create a python web-scraper with scrapy on a MacOS Catalina version 10.15.7 .

I need to setup scrapy but I'm having an issue. When I try to install scrapy in my terminal using
**`sudo pip3 install scrapy`**

[Terminal Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fDeJ.png)

It shows that all requirements are already satisfied which is all fine and dandy however, when I run the command

`scrapy`

I get an output of

> -bash: scrapy: command not found
> [Terminal Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ABKn.png)

how could I fix this issue?

Comment: create virtual environment with pip and then run above command.

Comment: @soheshdoshi Thank you! [link](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your whole environment or how you want to use `scrapy` ("globally" as in the command line or as part of a Python project.)

You are using `pip3` so when you invoke `scrapy` it might be looking in Python 2, not Python 3, locations. If you continue to use `pip3` then you could try to invoke `scrapy` like this;

```
python3 -m scrapy
```

Or you can use `pyenv` and then you don't need to specify `pip3` and `python3` anymore;

```
pyenv local 3.7.9
pip install scrapy
scrapy
```

`pyenv` basically switches the "active" Python version in a directory. So you can have multiple versions of Python installed and different installed libraries, caches etc.

If you are using `scrapy` in a Python project then as soheshdoshi mentions you could use a virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv .
source ./bin/activate
pip install scrapy
scrapy
```

Comment: Above and beyond! Thank you so much!